# Can the browser change references to tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following Javascript code:

```
var bodyRef

function init(){
  bodyRef = document.body
}
```

The `init()` function is invoked at `body.onload`

Is it safe to use the `bodyRef` variable in other parts of my code, or is the browser free to change the reference of `document.body`?

Comment: There is one and only one `document.body` for the entire lifetime of your document.  iframes or other embedded objects may have their own `document` and `document.body`, but the `document` and `document.body` you're in will not change during the lifetime of your script and page.  One might ask why you're making a new global variable for an alias to `document.body` when you can just reference `document.body` anytime you need it?

Answer (score 0):

> is the browser free to change the reference of document.body

No, it can't. `document.body` always points to the body of the current frame.

> Is it safe to use the bodyRef variable in other parts of my code

Yes. It is. But make sure you don't assign something to `document.body`

Comment: But what happens if I modify the body? Cannot the browser implementation just allocate a different data structure and make `document.body` point to that?

Comment: what do you mean by "modifying body"?

Comment: Say, for example, that I later append an element to it.

Comment: no. Appending element will not change `document.body`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no, a script cannot change the reference of `document.body`. if you try to do `document.body = "something"` you will get a `HierarchyRequestError`.

next, even if it was able to be changed, it would not be a problem. For example, if you do

```
var a = 6;
var b = a;
a = 3;
console.log(b); //this will show 6
```

it will still point to the original value, so there shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT:

after testing this, I did realize a problem. Since it stores the original value, if you were to modify the DOM, `document.body` will be updated, but `bodyRef` will not update.

Comment: My worry is that the browser changes it due to some legal operation (adding or removing elements, etc.). Although my original pointer would be non-null, it would point to an outdated version of the body that is not the one displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the bodyRef variable in other parts of your code. And if you wish to change the bodyRef equals to something then it is okay like assigning `bodyRef = "something";` but you cannot `body.document = "something";`. After all the variable is bodyRef not the document.body and how do you expect to change bodyRef after changing the document.body?